# Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'AppRoutingModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I writng about create ticket but it happen error.I am stuck in a situation here. I am getting an error like this.

Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'AppRoutingModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

**My add-ticket Component Looks like this**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketService } from './../../services/ticket.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-ticket',
  templateUrl: './add-ticket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-ticket.component.scss']
})
export class AddTicketComponent implements OnInit {
  public ticketForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public ticketAPI: TicketService,
    public fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ticketAPI.getTicketsList();
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './pages/signup/signup.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './pages/profile/profile.component';
import { AddTicketComponent } from './pages/add-ticket/add-ticket.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { Component } from '@angular/Core';

// Routes
export const router: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'add-ticket', component: AddTicketComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    AddTicketComponent,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(router),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,

  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AngularFireDatabase, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: share your app-routing.module.ts file code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your routing module is declared with @NgModule looks **@** is missing.
Check the components too.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'cars',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/cars-list/cars-list.module').then(m => m.CarsListModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove AppRoutingModule from declarations

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the import in your **app.module.ts** file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/Core';
```

It's lowercase c, not uppercase

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```